# How to find a formula for these generating sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

It is given that $a_{0}=1$ , $b_{0}=0$ , $c_0=0$

$$
c_n= xc_{n-1}+x(x-1)a_{n-1}(3b_{n-1}+(x-2)a_{n-1}^{2}))
$$

$$
b_n=xb_{n-1}+x(x-1)a_{n-1}^{2}
$$

$$
a_n=xa_{n-1}+1
$$

where x is any constant.

Is there any method , I can get a formula for $c_n$ in terms of $c_0$ and x?

Comment: Your "b" in the first equation is missing an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $$a_n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ if $x\ne 1$
and inserting this term in the next equation we obtain
$$b(n)=x^{n-1} \left(c_1+\frac{x^2 \left(-x^{-n}+x^{n+3}-(2 n+3)
   x^2+(2 n+3) x\right)}{(x-1)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes , $a_n$ can be calcuated but it gets difficult to calculate $c_n$ so i am looking for the best possible method to calculate $c_n$ .

Comment: Have you tried to insert that formula then in the other equations?

Comment: Yes , I have tried and I am having problem in that .

Comment: Well $b_n$ seems fine but how to calculate $c_n$ ?

Comment: this takes time for me